# por que no puedo depurar mi servicio de windows?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, windows-service

tengo un problema , cuando intento ejecutar un servicio de windows pongo 2 puntos de interrupcion uno en el metodo OnStart y el otro en OnStop , se que para depurar debo dar click en la opcion de "adjuntar al proceso" y antes de dar click ahi pues iniciarlo desde el servicio de windows , hasta todo bien , el unico problema es que este solo entra al metodo de OnStop y no entra al OnStart por que? necesito realmente depurar en esa parte ya que hay muchos procesos , tendra algo que ver con el tiempo establecido? esta es una clase comun que tiene algunas propidades y metodos
se llama "ServicioGenerado":

```
 public void OnStart()
    {

        this.ActualizaEventLog(strServicioNombre, "OnStart - Inicio");
        
        miServiceController = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController(strServicioNombre);

        try
        {
            if (this.CargaConfiguracion() == false)
            {
                this.ActualizaEventLog(strServicioNombre, "No se ha cargado la configuración del servicio.");

                return;
            }

            miLog.ActualizaLog("OnStart - Inicio", Logguer.Tipo.Information);

            string strTexto = string.Empty;

            strTexto = "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------";
            miLog.ActualizaLog(strTexto, Logguer.Tipo.Information);

            strTexto = "Inicia proceso.";
            miLog.ActualizaLog(strTexto, Logguer.Tipo.Information);

            this.Procesar();

            strTexto = "Fin del proceso.";
            miLog.ActualizaLog(strTexto, Logguer.Tipo.Information);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.ManejaExcepcionServicio(ex);
            this.OnStop();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (miLog != null) { miLog.ActualizaLog("OnStart - Fin", Logguer.Tipo.Information); }

            this.ActualizaEventLog(strServicioNombre, "OnStart - Fin");
        }
    }

    private void GenerarCopiado()
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
        //obtenemos los valores de estas variables mediante el archivo de configuracion mediante el nombre
        //que tienen estos en el archivo de configuracion.
        PATH_ORIGINALES = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PathFotos_Ori"];
        PATH_NORTE = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PathFotos_Norte"];
        PATH_REFORMA = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PathFotos_Reforma"];
        PATH_REFORMA_IN = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PathFotos_Reforma_IN"];
        PATH_MURAL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PathFotos_Mural"];
        PATH_MURAL_IN = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PathFotos_Mural_IN"];
        PATH_MURAL_PRINT_IN = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PathFotos_Mural_IN_Print"];
        PATH_MURAL_OUT = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PathFotos_Mural_OUT"];
        PATH_MURAL_PRINT_OUT = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PathFotos_Mural_OUT_Print"];
        //verificamos si se escribio en la linea de comandos cuando se ejecute la aplicacion la fecha 
        // de ser asi tomamos ese valor y lo amacenamos en la variable de fecha
        string[] _args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
        if (_args.Length > 0)
        {
            fecha = _args[1].Trim();
        }
        else
        {
            //de no ser asi automaticamente tomara la fecha actual con un formato de mes/dia/año
            fecha = $"{DateTime.Now.Month}/{DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).Day}/{DateTime.Now.Year}";
        }

        //ejecutamos el store procedure mediante el metodo "execTable" de la clase dal 
        //pasandole como argumentos el nombre del procedimiento almacenado y la fecha
        tabla = dal.execTable<string>("SpImp_FotosMultiPlaza", "'" + fecha + "'");

        //verificamos si las filas de resultado de la ejecucion del store procedure es mayor a 0
        if (tabla.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            //de ser asi se imprimira el siguiente texto "Hay (numero de filas de resultado de la ejecucion
            //del store procedure) fotos para copiar a otras plazas..."
            Console.WriteLine("Hay " + tabla.Rows.Count.ToString() + " fotos para copiar a otras plazas...");

            //recorremos todos los registros del resultado del store procedure 
            for (int i = 0; i < tabla.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                //desglose aumentara en 1
                desglose += 1;
                //si la primera columna de cada  iteracion tiene el valor de 26969498 entonces se mostrara por pantalla
                if (tabla.Rows[i][0].ToString() == "26969498")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(tabla.Rows[i][0].ToString());
                }
                copiaFotos(tabla.Rows[i][0].ToString(), tabla.Rows[i][1].ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(tabla.Rows[i][2].ToString()), tabla.Rows[i][3].ToString(), "Galeria");
                copiaFotos(tabla.Rows[i][0].ToString(), tabla.Rows[i][1].ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(tabla.Rows[i][2].ToString()), tabla.Rows[i][3].ToString(), "Portada");
                Console.WriteLine("Copiando " + (i + 1).ToString() + " de " + tabla.Rows.Count.ToString() + ": " + tabla.Rows[i][0].ToString() + "...");

            }

            //copia de otras plazas hacia norte
            tabla = dal.execTable<string>("spIMP_FotosHaciaELNorte", "'" + fecha + "'");
            if (tabla.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                desglose = 0;
                Console.WriteLine("Hay " + tabla.Rows.Count.ToString() + " foto para importar a Norte...");
                for (int i = 0; i < tabla.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    desglose += 1;
                    ObtenFotos(tabla.Rows[i][0].ToString(), tabla.Rows[i][1].ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(tabla.Rows[i][3].ToString()));
                    Console.WriteLine("Importando " + (i + 1).ToString() + " de " + tabla.Rows.Count.ToString() + "...");
                }
            }
            tabla.Dispose();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stop this service.
    /// </summary>
    /// }
    public void OnStop()
    {
        try
        {
            bolCorrer = false;

            if (miLog != null) { miLog.ActualizaLog("OnStop - Inicio", Logguer.Tipo.Information); }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (miLog != null) { miLog.ActualizaLog(ex.ToString(), Logguer.Tipo.Error); }

            if (miCentinela == null) { throw; } else { if (miCentinela.AgregarError() == false) { throw; } }
        }
        finally { if (miLog != null) { miLog.ActualizaLog("OnStop - Fin", Logguer.Tipo.Information); } }
        //timer.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void Procesar()
    {
        bolCorrer = true;
        //int intPoleoIntervalo = miConfiguracionVO.PoleoIntervalo * 1000;
        int intPoleoIntervalo = 60 * 1000;
        int intIntervaloCorto = miConfiguracionVO.IntervaloCorto * 1000;
        

        while (bolCorrer == true)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.Sleep(intPoleoIntervalo);

                //Manda classe que genere algo
                //this.ClaseTest();
                GenerarCopiado();

                

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string strMensaje = "El servicio se ha detenido por acumulación de errores.";
                if (this.ManejaExcepcionProcesar(ex, strMensaje) == false)
                {
                    miServiceController.Stop();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

y tengo otra clase que esa vendria siendo en si el servicio en general y ahi instancio esta clase  en el servicio de windows(clase) y desde ahi mando a llamar metodos y propiedades de la clase "ServicioGenerador"

```
partial class WinService : ServiceBase
{

    Thread miWorkerThread;

    ServicioGenerador miServicioGenerador = new ServicioGenerador();

    public WinService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {

        try
        {
            ThreadStart miThreadStart = new ThreadStart(miServicioGenerador.OnStart);

            miWorkerThread = new Thread(miThreadStart);

            miWorkerThread.Start();

            //Console.WriteLine("se ha iniciado el servicio");
            EventLog.WriteEntry("se inicio el servicio  ");
        }
        catch (Exception) { this.Stop(); }
    }
    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        try { miServicioGenerador.OnStop(); }

        catch (Exception) { this.Stop(); }

        Console.WriteLine("se ha detenido el servicio!");
        //EventLog.WriteEntry("se ha detenido el servicio");
        timer.Stop();
    }

    /// <summary> 
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Component Designer generated code

    /// <summary> 
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {

        components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        this.ServiceName = "WinService";

    }

    #endregion
    
}
```

el servicio generador se llama "WinService.Designer.cs" y muy probablemente tiene algo que ver en el codigo , no tengo alguna idea segun yo si lo incio el servicio desde los servicios deberia poder entrar al metodo onStart de la clase de servicio de windows o por su nombre "WinService.Design.cs"

Answer (score 0):

> el unico problema es que este solo entra al metodo de OnStop y no
> entra al OnStart por que?

**Este es un gran problema, ya que el `Services Control Manager` define un límite de 30 segundos en todos los intentos de iniciar el servicio, pero si defines "breakpoints" dentro de `OnStart()`, no iniciará el servicio.**

Te sugiero revisar la documentación donde se indica este problema:

[Solución de problemas: depuración de servicios de Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/troubleshooting-debugging-windows-services)

> Cuando depura una aplicación de servicio de Windows, su servicio y el
> Administrador de servicios de Windows (Windows Service Manager) interactúan. El Administrador de
> servicios inicia su servicio llamando al método OnStart y luego espera
> 30 segundos para que regrese el método OnStart. Si el método no
> regresa en este tiempo, el administrador muestra un error de que el
> servicio no se puede iniciar.
>
> Cuando depura el método OnStart como se describe en Cómo: depurar
> aplicaciones de servicio de Windows, **debe tener en cuenta este período
> de 30 segundos. Si coloca un punto de interrupción en el método
> OnStart y no lo recorre en 30 segundos, el administrador no iniciará
> el servicio**.

**Personalmente, prefiero realizar una `Windows Application,` donde mande llamar el proceso que se realiza en `onStart()` y ahí puedo depurar con facilidad, al terminar paso este código a mi `Windows Service`.**